# How do I calculate number of times a data is accessed?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to track number of times a data is accessed from a table. How can I do this with PHP and MySQL?

Comment: count() and group by are your friends. Read mysql manual.

Comment: nick - i think the question is about number of selects that a given row experiences?  not sure this is possible..

Comment: Are you looking to count the number of times a specific row was accessed or the whole table?

Comment: Please forgive me if I misundestood. ;)

Comment: @Randy Its not unless you count it manually. However if your wanting to track INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE operations you can create a trigger that automatically updates a row, which is the best way to do it imo.

Comment: @Gunnar - i suppose some kind of manual count may be possible - i was thinking maybe you could find the parsed sql in the dictionary cache somewhere, but that does not tell you which rows were accessed. - totally agree on the other DML commands in triggers.

Answer (score 2):

Add an extra number column to the table, starting at 0, then remember to add one to the column every time you access a row. For example: `UPDATE Tbl1 SET counter = counter + 1 WHERE name ='joe_bloggs'`

Comment: Good point (slightly pedantic). At least with this method you have a choice.